# Light-weight Database for storing user preferences of widgets

Tags: php, database, database-design, widget, dashboard

I'm looking for a database that I can distribute with a web application, that will store user preferences for various widgets.

A good example is the kind of database design that apple uses to store information about its widgets. So the weather widget stores location, while the notes widget stores notes.

I think I'm looking for a document-oriented database, but I'm not really sure.

Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 1):

sqlite now comes as standard with PHP, and [g]dbm was there for a very long time but I believe has been dropped recently (can't seem to see any replacement for it - chdb?).

C.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use localStorage see support details here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html#localstorage

Comment: but only a selected few browsers support this at the time of this writing

Comment: you mean like the big 4, Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, IE8, Chrome 4+ which all support it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [CouchDB](http://couchdb.org/) or [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/) as far as document-oriented database. It really depends though what is being stored. A key-value store such as [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) might also work.

Personally, I've used a lot of CouchDB and redis so far. CouchDB powers our storage backend (citation-related data) and redis is our session store.

Care to elaborate how people can help you further?